# rows and column entries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am working on the Visual Studio using MFC. I want to make a table having rows and columns. Rows with four entries and columns entries have no limits. Which toolbox I should use in order to proceed in this task. I tried listbox, combo box, mfc vslist but these are not fulfilling my requirements. Kindly guide me which tool box I should use for this purpose. I get some kind of info from that link http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/listbox.htm but this is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, you can use the standard [List Control (CListCtrl)](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/listcontrol.htm) in report mode or, if more advanced features are needed, a full-blown grid control. In codeproject you can find these two, which are quite widely used:

- [MFC Grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27)
- [The Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page)

I don't know if they work well with VS 2010, but the first one, according to the link provided, it does. The Ultimate Grid says it works up to VS2005, but I'm using it with VS2008. I don't remember if I had to change anything in order to make it work, though.

Anyway, I would first give the standard CListCtrl a try, and if you find you need more, try any of the others.

Comment: in the first link; it is written : Construction
OK - so how do you use it?
The underlying class of the grid control is CGridCtrl which is derived from CWnd. To use it, either use the MS Visual C++ dialog editor to place a custom control on a dialog, and enter "MFCGridCtrl" (no quotes) as the Class name. To subclass the control using the DDX mechanism (this will be done by default by the ClassWizard) use the DDX_GridControl function instead of the DDX_Control function (just manually change the ClassWizard entry).

Comment: I tried alot to do this stuff but it gives an error NATIVE CODE EXIT WITH 0. I placed a custom control on the dialog and ADD CLASS MFCGridCtrl and simulated. It gives error.

Comment: @Nabeel I have never used the MFC Grid Ctrl, so I can't help much. Maybe you should check the demo projects, or ask in the codeproject page (or even ask a more specific question here in stackoverflow). I don't have much time right now, so I can't test it. Maybe later. Sorry.